# Script de afiliados com ajuda equipa (Problema com recursividade)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou a escrever um código em CodeIgniter, para divulgação de um software de cloud storage gratuito e sem fins lucrativos.

Contudo, para funcionar, vamos ter um sistema de afiliados, que atribui uma certa quantidade de armazenamento a quem mais divulgar, bem como aos membros acima.

A dificuldade maior, é que o sistema de afiliados é forcado, ou seja, cada nível so pode ter no máximo 5 utilizadores, quando está completo, procura nos níveis abaixo para incorporar nos membros abaixo.

**Esta é a estrutura da tabela users:**

```
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created      | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| join_ip      | varchar(30)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_active    | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| is_deleted   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| name         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email        | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country_id   | int(2)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sponsor_id   | int(20)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| upline_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**A função que tenho no Model em PHP (CodeIgniter) é esta:**

```
public function getAvailableSponsor($sponsor = NULL)
{
    if ($sponsor == NULL) return array();
    $this->db->select('id, sponsor_name, sponsor_id, upline_id')
        -> from('users')
        -> where('upline_id', $sponsor);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result();
    $total = count($result);

    if ($total < 2){
        return $sponsor;
    }else {
        foreach ($result as $row){
            return $this->getAvailableSponsor($row->id);
        }           
    } 

}
```

A sequência que estou a ter de resultado é esta:

```
Sponsor ID 1 has 2 sponsored users FULL. 
Sponsor ID 2 has 2 sponsored users FULL. 
Sponsor ID 4 has 0 sponsored users Available :)

Next upline: 4 (AQUI deveria de ser 3, e nao 4.)
```

Query na base de dados:

```
 select id, sponsor_id, upline_id from users;

 +----+------------+-----------+
 | id | sponsor_id | upline_id |
 +----+------------+-----------+
 |  1 |          0 |         0 |
 |  2 |          1 |         1 |
 |  3 |          1 |         1 |
 |  4 |          1 |         2 |
 |  5 |          1 |         2 |
 +----+------------+-----------+
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Explica melhor o teu problema. O que queres fazer exatamente?

Comment: Olá Jorge. O que quero fazer é que os registos sejam inseridos pela ordem os seus respectivos niveis. Por exemplo se o sistema for de 2 users por niveis, o user 1, insere o 2 e o 3. Depois o 1 volta a inserir mais 2, mas serao ja inseridos debaixo do 2. Este artigo explica de forma detalhada o que será necessario fazer,  mas aplicado a este software gratis e opensource.

Comment: Então queres um sistema de inserção de utilizadores em árvore?

Comment: Sim, de forma a que a árvore fique preenchida automaticamente até N níveis.

Comment: A ideia é mais ou menos a mesma de esta: http://jam.jrox.com/kb/article/what-is-forced-matrix

Comment: Entendi. Tu estás a percorrer os sub-níveis da esquerda para a direita, por isso, pode ser que o 4 esteja no mesmo nível que o 3 mas apareça primeiro, faz um *select all* a base de dados e posta aqui a resposta.

Comment: Pergunta editada. So trouxe os campos mais importantes

Comment: Como estas a fazer recursivamente o que acontece é que tu vais seguir dois caminhos diferente, por rotas diferentes.

 id=4 tem pai id=2
 id=3 tem pai id=1

ou seja, são dois caminhos diferente na recursividade. E por algum motivo o caminho por pai id=2 é mais rápido a verificar que tem um filho livre.

Comment: Pois, esse é o meu problema. Eu sou um programador com conhecimento médio, mas no que toca a recursividade tenho muitas dificuldades.

Comment: No seu foreach, quando executa o return ele não continua o for, sai na primeira iteração.

Answer (score 1):

Podes tentar algo com sub-select como:

```
SELECT a.id FROM users a
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM users b WHERE upline_id = a.id) < 2
ORDER BY a.id
```